# Metallic state in 2D

Tags: condensed-matter, superconductivity, symmetry-breaking

Mermin Wagner theorem prevents any spontaneous breaking of continuous symmetry for short ranged interactions for dimensions, D $\leq$2 for any finite temperature. So I understand that superconducting state is not possible theoretically in 2D as there is breaking of gauge symmetry in superconductors. But why metallic or superconducting state is not possible in 2D? What kind of symmetry breaking occurs when an insulator (or semiconductor) undergoes MIT (metal insulator transition or vice versa)?